# Binding misunderstanding not getting properties set

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following XAML and am trying to implement properties on two labels inside so I can set the captions on them when the controls are instantiated in the XAML. At a later stage this will be from code as well. Please can you tell me what am I missing about databinding, and what I should be doing? I am quite new to WPF.

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:p="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        xmlns:ctrl="clr-namespace:xCtrl"
        Title="MainWindow" Width="525" ResizeMode="NoResize" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowStyle="None">
    <Window.Resources>
        <p:Style TargetType="ctrl:BSHintButton" x:Key="BSStyle">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">

                        <Grid x:Name="xgrid" Height="50" Width="500" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="430
                                                      "/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label x:Name="xLabel" Content="{Binding Caption}"
                                   Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                   Margin="10,8,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                   Grid.RowSpan="2" Width="Auto"
                                   FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="14"
                                   FontWeight="Bold" Height="Auto"/>
                            <Label x:Name="xHint" Content="{Binding HintText}"
                                   Foreground="DarkCyan" Grid.Column="1"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto"
                                   Margin="10,-2,0,0" Grid.Row="1"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto"
                                   FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="14"/>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="xFocus"
                                Stroke="Orange"
                                StrokeThickness="1"
                                RadiusX = "4" RadiusY="4" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsEnabled="True" Visibility="Hidden"       
                                       />
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                  Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="xgrid" Property="Background">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.504,1.5" StartPoint="0.504,0.01">
                                            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"/>
                                            <GradientStop Color="Gold"  Offset="0.1"/>
                                            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.8"/>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>

                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                                <Setter TargetName="xFocus" Property="Visibility"
                   Value="Visible" />

                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="ctrl:OfficeBSHintButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource BSStyle}" />

    </Window.Resources>


    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,0,0.001">
        <ctrl:BSHintButton x:Name="Button1" Tag ="2" Click="Button1_Click" Caption="caption1" HintText="Hint1">
        </ctrl:BSHintButton>
        <ctrl:BSHintButton x:Name="Button2" Tag ="1" Click="Button1_Click" Caption="caption1" HintText="Hint2">
        </ctrl:BSHintButton>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**Code for the class**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace xCtrl
{
    public class BSHintButton : Button
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CaptionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Caption",
                                    typeof(string),
                                    typeof(Label)
                                    );
        public static readonly DependencyProperty HintTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("HintText",
                                    typeof(string),
                                    typeof(Label)
                                    );
        public string Caption
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(CaptionProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CaptionProperty, value); }
        }
        public string HintText
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(HintTextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(HintTextProperty, value); }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Binding applies to the `DataContext` (models, etc...), where as `TemplateBinding` applies to the templated control (the button). You should use `{TemplateBinding Caption}`.

Comment: If I change to TemplateBinding it has no idea what I am on about as it cannot find the members for Caption, HintText.  Also it cannot find thst statc members for the DependencyProperty on Button.

Comment: I was just rying INotifyPropertyChanged but that does not work either, so frustrated now.  I assume taht because coming from the style?

Answer (score 2):

Without [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it can be difficult or impossible to know for sure what the problem is, never mind test a solution. But looking over your code, the most obvious thing I notice wrong with it is that you are declaring your dependency properties incorrectly.

The owner of the dependency property is the type in which the property will be declared, not the type which you expect to use as the target for a binding.

So your code should look like this instead:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CaptionProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Caption",
                                typeof(string),
                                typeof(BSHintButton)
                                );
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HintTextProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("HintText",
                                typeof(string),
                                typeof(BSHintButton)
                                );
```

Having the wrong owner may prevent WPF from correctly handling the binding declared in the XAML. It's my hope and expectation that fixing your code as above will allow the binding to work.

If not though, please edit your question so that it includes a good code example. Without one, it's not possible to example your specific problem "in situ", to debug it properly.

Speaking of debugging, you should also get into the habit of checking the debug output for your program. When binding doesn't work, often WPF has emitted one or more error messages to the debug output. Some of the time, these messages are even helpful. :)